# How to force page-break-before to work inside a table?

Tags: css, html-table, page-break

Is there any way to force page break before the row in the table? I found out it could be done by replacing table elements with DIVs, but I don't want to do it because it would mean to rewrite many, many files, it could take a week. And all other solutions I found doesn't work for me. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You can use `tr:first-child { margin-top: 20px }` CSS to add a space before the first table row.

Comment: I don´t see how this could help... :/

Comment: You're right, can't use that on a `TR`. Use a table padding instead. i.e.: `table { padding-top: 20px; }` or for exactly one line: `table { padding-top: 1em; }`.

Comment: Im not sure if we understand each other :) Just adding some space won´t solve my problem, since the table is dynamic :(

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Could you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Posted ;) By dynamic I mean that everytime table has got different number of rows and adding a space won´t resolve this... I need some solid page break which I could place to,before or after some table element. Then I could set some condition to it (for example first element won´t be broken etc.), but main problem is just how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border:2px solid black; border-radius:10px; width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
<table width="100%" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed; border:1px solid transparent;">
<?
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>
<tr style="background:#FFFFFF">';

    <td style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;' width=100><? echo $row['znacka'];?></td>
    <td style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;'><? echo $row['nazev'];?></td>
    <td style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;' width=90 align=center><? echo $row['zn_zatrideni'];?></td>
    <td style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;' width=90 align=right><? echo number_format($row['mnozstvi'],2,'.',' ');?></td>
    <td style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;' width=40 align=center><? echo $row['mj'];?></td>
    <td style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;' width=100 align=right><? if($row['mnozstvi']!=0) echo number_format($row['cena']/$row['mnozstvi'],0,'.',' '); else echo '0';?></td>
<?  if($odd==true){?>
        <td class="stred_b"  width=100 align=right><? echo number_format(($row['cena_min']/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></td>
        <td class="stred_g"  width=100 align=right><? echo number_format(($row['cena']/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></td>
        <td class="stred_r"  width=100 align=right><? echo number_format(($row['cena_max']/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></td>
<?  } else{?>
        <td class="svetle_b"  width=100 align=right><? echo number_format(($row['cena_min']/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></td>
        <td class="svetle_g"  width=100 align=right><? echo number_format(($row['cena']/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></td>
        <td class="svetle_r"  width=100  align=right><? echo number_format(($row['cena_max']/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></td>          
    <?} $odd=!$odd; ?>
</tr>
<?}?>
<tr>
<th colspan=3></th><th colspan=3 align=right style="background:black; color:white" >Celková cena stupně IZ:</th>
<th class="svetle_b"  align=right><? echo number_format(($celkovaCenaMin/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></th>
<th class="svetle_g"  align=right><? echo number_format(($celkovaCena/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></th>
<th class="svetle_r"  align=right><? echo number_format(($celkovaCenaMax/1000) ,0 ,'.' ,$oddelovac_tisicu);?></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?}?>
```

Comment: You can simply add `page-break-before:always` of `TR` element's `STYLE` attribute to put a page break before that element.

Comment: I already tried that, but only case when this works, is when I add it in the TABLE element... If I add it to the TR, it just breaks once before the table and the rest of the table is unbroken.

Comment: Then try on the first cell of the row. e.g.: `#TheRow>TD:first-child {page-break-before:always;}` or `#TheRow>TH:first-child {page-break-before:always;}`. Note that this must be specified in a CSS.